# Export paginated table in html to PDF,CSV,XLS

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, bootstrap-table

I am trying to export html table using js provided by [Ngiriraj Table Export Demo](http://ngiriraj.com/pages/htmltable_export/demo.php). My table is paginated by *bootstrap-table.js* .
When I am exporting data in any format only 1 table page is getting exported.
 Also, while exporting pdf, I am only getting only 4 columns in pdf.
The code is attached below.

Jsp page:

```
<div style="padding: 10px;">
    <br>
    <table id="table" data-search="true" data-show-columns="true"
        data-pagination="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <c:forEach items="${keys}" var="keys">
                    <th data-field="${keys}" data-sortable="true">${keys}</th>
                </c:forEach>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default export">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Download grid data as</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#"
                    onClick="$('#table').tableExport({type:'excel',escape:'false'});">XLS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"
                    onClick="$('#table').tableExport({type:'csv',escape:'false'});">CSV</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"
                    onClick="$('#table').tableExport({type:'pdf',escape:'false'});">PDF</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"
                    onClick="$('#table').tableExport({type:'json',escape:'false'});">JSON</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I have included .js files as:

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/tableExport.js"></script>
<script
    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/base64.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/sprintf.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jspdf.js"></script>
```

For all above .js files please refer [Ngiriraj Table Export demo](http://ngiriraj.com/pages/htmltable_export/demo.php).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it is because that plugin is designed to work like that :)

Comment: :) You are right. As I was implementing **bootstrap-table.js**, I just had to use **bootstrap-table-export.js** which is extension to bootstrap-table. It automatically solves every export problem.. Anyways. Thanks.. :)

Comment: I use that plugin once(Ngiriraj table export) and I have to modify the plugin in order to export the whole table and not just the current-selected page of the pagination...a real pain in...